# Multiple randomized rows in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to make a customized randomized data template where I'm able to get a certain amount of rows (let's say 100 in this example) containing randomized data, as I often need this kind of data for testing. The following code gives me this output:

```
   ID    Name  Age  City  Telephone    Birthday
    1  Harold   60  4000   21327950  2020-07-29
```

But I need to be able to specify the amount of rows I need somewhere, and preferably before the randomization of values, as I don't want to copy line 1 100 times and then do an iteration of all the rows. I hope this is possible in the current coding structure I'm using, as I want the model to be as agile as possible, so more columns can be added smoothly if needed. Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
import names

# List of Columns
data = {
    'ID': 1,
    'Name': names.get_first_name(names.get_full_name),
    'Age': np.random.randint(18, 65),
    'City': np.random.randint(2, 8)*1000,
    'Telephone': np.random.randint(11111111, 99999999),
    'Birthday': [datetime.date.today()],
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the output.
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

# List of Columns
n = 100

data = {
    'ID': [i+1 for i in range(n)],
    'Age': [np.random.randint(18, 65) for i in range(n)],
    'City': [np.random.randint(2, 8)*1000 for i in range(n)],
    'Telephone': [np.random.randint(11111111, 99999999) for i in range(n)]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the output.
print(df)

>>>

     ID  Age  City  Telephone
0     1   43  6000   25571478
1     2   60  5000   89030075
2     3   33  7000   41082092
3     4   21  7000   95900727
4     5   64  3000   51121306
..  ...  ...   ...        ...
95   96   51  6000   21656354
96   97   46  3000   91976030
97   98   60  3000   58243519
98   99   41  3000   80755166
99  100   57  4000   96513484

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Ofc. That's an smart solution. Why didn't I come up with that :) Anyway - Thank you very much for your help!